# Python function to identify 0 as a missing value in numerical columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis, missing-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I need to write a function where zero in a numeric column is identified as missing value in python. Can anyone help me with how to do that?

```
#numerical columns in df dataframe
df_num = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')
```

After this I need a function to convert all zeroes in df_num to be picked as missing values.

This is what I tried

```
df_num.replace(0,np.nan)
```

But the dataset is not being changed.

Is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: You do `df_num = df_num.replace(0,np.nan)`?

Comment: that throws an error

Comment: I tried `df_num.replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)` and this worked now

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you found a solution to your question, scroll all the way down and post it as an answer. Please don't answer your question in a comment. You can accept your own answer after 48 hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would be missing there is to assign it to the column or columns from which it is expected to convert the 0s into missing values

```py
df_num['numeric_column'] = df_num['numeric_column'].replace(0, np.nan)
```

And finally, display the dataframe to see the changes with `print(df_num)`.
I hope it helps, greetings!